# Recursively copy/backup all .php files to .php.bak files and keep them in their current paths

Tags: shell, command, backup

I am not sure how to word this question to find the solution easily online, so after much searching I thought I would ask here.

I access my website's files using bitvise ssh client and I use command lines for various grep and sed functions that I've been recently taught, but I can't seem to find a simple way to do this:

What is the command line to make a backup copy (.bak) of EVERY file that ends in .php?  I am looking for the command to instantly make a backup of every php file at once, so when I go into my files I see things like...

index.php

index.php.bak

For every php file.

Also, what is the command line to do this for EVERY file at once, regardless of extension?

Comment: don't forget to click the checkmark under the up down arrows if this is something that helped.

Comment: Consider changing title to something more direct (fe. *Recursively copy all *.php to *.php.bak in current path*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be awesome to see a solution that uses `xargs` or `find`'s `-exec`.

But here is how can do this with a shell loop and `find`:

*Note, this recursively backs up files in sub directories.*

For .php files:

```
find . -iname '*.php' -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do cp "$file" "$file.bak"; done
```

For all files:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do cp "$file" "$file.bak"; done
```

For all files that have an extension:

```
find . -iname '*.*' -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do cp "$file" "$file.bak"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `cp` command

enter the dir that you have all the .php files then type

`cp *.php temp/` where `temp` is a directory  in the current directory. The `*` means `all`

if you just want to copy the whole folder you could

`cp -R foldername destinationArea`

Comment: I do not want to move them to a different directory.  I want every php file on my entire site, in all directories, to have a (.bak) file right under them.  There is a sed command that does this after making a global change with sed but I want to know how to do this without making a change with sed.  So for instance if I go into the plugins directory, I'd see plugin1.php and right under it would be plugin1.php.bak  ...and the same for every file in every directory.

Comment: It looks like the answer myninjaname provided will do exactly what I want, but if cp can also do exactly this with less to remember I would love to see how.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: He does cp as well. He just showed you if you didn't know where the files were then it does it for you. Mine assumes you know where they are. Please hit the little check mark next to the up down arrow if it helped you.

Comment: The reason you can't use only the `cp` command is because if multiple files are matched, it expects the destination to be a directory (and you can't use `--backup` having a `--target-directory` matching the current directory).

Comment: Huh? I just tested if `cp *.php temp/` where temp is the directory to back up all the files, and it does....

Comment: The user wants to suffix the files with .bak keeping them in the current directory (fe. `./my_file.php` -> `./my_file.php.bak`).

Comment: Thats fine but he also might what to just put them in another directory. Thats why you posted your answer and I posted mine... Its ok to have different solutions here.

Comment: Yes Jay I appreciate both solutions and both may come in handy at different times. There may come a time when I want to move them into another directory, however, for this instance I stated I wanted all the files in my entire site to be backed up and for those .bak files to remain in the same directories that their originals were found. So, after testing them, @myninjaname solution does exactly what I want across my entire site perfectly. Thank you both, though. I appreciate it!